# Creating "wrapper" function for generating location-specific plots

Tags: r, wrapper

I have a section of code which generates plots for particular genetic data when region = x (see example section for region=Central below), however I want to create a "wrapper" function in R for this to reduce the amount of fluff, where if region = x, run a PCA on this regions data, and then generate a plot (pic included). Is there a way to do this smoothly? I am very new to coding so hope this is clear!

```r
Central <- autoplot(pca, data = G5.ID3, colour = 'Region') + scale_color_viridis(discrete=TRUE,option="D") +
  gghighlight(Region == "Central Otago", use_group_by = FALSE, use_direct_label = FALSE, label_key = Region) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) + 
  annotate(geom="text", x=-Inf, y=Inf, hjust=-0.1, vjust=1.6, size = 4, label="Central Otago")
```

data for location = Central :
[image: data for location = Central]

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. `.data` should be added to `data` parameter in your PCA code.

```
library(tidyverse)

my_function <- function(.region, .data) {
  .data <- filter(.data, region == .region)
  
  # Code for `pca`
  
  autoplot(pca, data = .data) +
    scale_color_viridis(discrete=TRUE,option="D") +
    theme(legend.position = "none",
          axis.title.x=element_blank(),
          axis.text.x=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
          axis.title.y=element_blank(),
          axis.text.y=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) + 
    annotate(geom="text", x=-Inf, y=Inf, hjust=-0.1, vjust=1.6, size = 4, label=.region)
}

region <- c("Central Otago", "B")
names(region) <- region

my_plots <- region %>% 
  map(my_function,
      .data = G5.ID3)

# Check out the plot for central Otago
my_plots[["Central Otago"]]
```